# How to find a memory leak that isn;t a memory leak?

Tags: c++, debugging, memory, memory-leaks

I have large program, I am noticing that memory steadily grows until my machine cannot handle it and I have to restart it.

Normally this would be a memory leak, however I have used libasan and valgrind and neither can find a leak.

What I suspect is happening is that somewhere inside the code a dynamic structure is growing without control due to a logic error. For example, a vector that is getting reserved over and over again with ever bigger values. As far as asan is concerned that is not a memleak since it gets cleaned up upon program termination, but would have the exact same effects.

What tools can be used to try to identify which objects in memory are biggest? i.e. trying to locate a "memory leak" that is not actually a leak.

Comment: It *is* a memory leak, but probably one that gets cleaned up when you exit the program. You have to look through the code for all memory allocations (including adding elements to vectors or strings), which are never deleted (i.e. the vectors and strings are only added to, but never removed from).

Comment: Another possibility is that you create a lot of copies of large objects (again, vectors and strings are likely candidates) but the copies are never destructed. Consider using references (or possibly pointers) instead of storing copies.

Comment: I do try to use references as much as possible, and this code seemed to run fine for a while on a machine with many more resources. There's thousands of LOCs, tracing all possible allocations by hand is not feasible.

Comment: Then you need to add *logging*. Log each time a new object is created (including adding in a container) and when objects are destructed. Make sure that all creations are matched by a destruction.

Comment: A memory profiler (like valgrind's Massif tool or the "Allocations" tool that is part of MacOS/X'/X-Code's Instruments package) can be very helpful here; when your program is in the bloated/fault state, it can tell you what allocations are making up the bulk of the process's RAM usage.  That in turn will give you a hint as to where your non-leak-leak is coming from.

Comment: Which platform are you using? If it's not a true leak,  then it may be memory fragmentation or some aggressive memory allocation strategies without shrink.  I have quite a lot of experience in this area with Linux. There are several approaches:`tcmalloc` profiler, system profilers like `ebpf`, `bcc`, `linux perf` tool.

Comment: MSVC has a heap snapshot function, which shows a cumulative tree of all allocated objects, with locations in the code where they were allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try https://github.com/vmware/chap

It will help you because it calculates the graph of references between allocations and also recognizes many of the various kinds of allocations used by std containers.

Run your process, uninstrumented, until it is significantly larger than you would expect then use gcore to gather a live core, open the core in chap and start with the suggestions in https://github.com/vmware/chap/blob/master/USERGUIDE.md#analyzing-memory-growth

Answer (score 0):

I was recommended heaptrack and heaptrack_gui to resolve this issue on linux and it does exactly what I needed to solve the issue. It shows you a flame graph of your memory allocations based on the call hierarchy, so you can narrow down, call by call, where you are likely over allocating.

For the curious, the underlying problem in my application was a singular vulkan image whose memory I forgot to free.